# Drupal 6 Login Page Content

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

The internal website at my company is run on Drupal and on the User Login Page and after you login it lists information. However, I can't find anyway to update this information and the page that is named the same thing has no content. It's currently set up as a node, but I need to update it as the current information is someone who doesn't work with the company anymore.

Please help.

Comment: Oh?!!! Are you still with 6?

Comment: I started working at a company and their intranet is on a very old server running Drupal 6. I'm just basically doing patch work until we move to a new website. But I was trying to figure out how to fix the Login Page since the information is up to date.